# Kurento restreaming

Tags: video-streaming, kurento

Playing with Kurento Media Server, i realized that while it scales linearly until about 500 streams, it's not behaving good after that point, and so far i was unable to scale it to 1000 streams on a server (even 4x stronger than the one from which it serves 500 streams with just 60% load). Exceptions during connections and all kinds of trouble begins from about 800 connections.

So my next plan is to run several Docker containers on one mighty server, each serving 500 connections, hopefully reaching 2500 streams on a double processor, 16 core Xeon with 128Gb of RAM. In order to do this, i need a way to re-stream one client stream to several other servers, i.e. achieve KMS-to-KMS streaming.

Is there any sample code of how to do it with the Kurento JS API?

Thanks!

Comment: I heard about the thing called 'PlumberEndpoint' but i can't find any example of how to use it..

Comment: Back to it. Still didn't find a good demo or a doc on PlumberEndpoint. Anyone can point at something?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [kurento-tree](http://doc-kurento-tree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html) project. It is written in Java, but you should be able to get an idea of how it is done, and port it to Node.js, as there is no JavaScript version.

Comment: It seems to be too complicated and does too much to find the main thing :(

Comment: Whel, what you are asking for is not easy at all... That's why there's a separated project for that! I'd recommend you use the project directly.

Comment: How do i use the project directly? Say i have server X, and a stack of identical servers a,b,c,... and i want every stream received from clients at X, be re-streamed to each of a,b,c, so that any client connecting to any of them will receive it. How is it done?

Comment: https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/blob/develop/kurento-one2many-with-plumbers/server.js this thing seems to be it. will it work on a modern release of Kurento?

Comment: If not, is there any equivalent or replacement?

Comment: Yes it will. You need to register the KMS instances in the kurento-tree server, so the server knows where to send media.

Comment: Here is what i think i need to do: hand-hack an SDP offer and, having a pipeline for the stream i want to restream to the other server, create an RTP endpoint by feeding it that SDP offer, then take an SDP answer from processing that offer, send it to the receiving server, and create a pipeline feeding from an RTP endpoint on it, initated by that said SDP answer used as an offer, and discarding the resuling answer because the 'slave' Kurento is not going to send anything to 'master'. Is that logic correct? Is it going to work this way?

Comment: Well, I would recommend using some sort of signaling to exchange SDPs and ICE candidates, and use WebRTc endpoints instead. That way you'll avoid one transcodification.